# Codeigniter - return an anchor() from function

Tags: php, codeigniter, return-value

probably a newb question here, but how do I return a CI anchor() call from within a function. I want to "hide" a button if a variable is set to a certain value.
CI's URL helper documentation: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

A pseudo example that won't work (can't return the URL helper `anchor('','')`:

```
$prevAvailCompID = 0;

function hideButton($prevCompID)
{
    if($prevCompID == 0)
    {
        return anchor('/getcomps/getSpecificComp/'.$prevCompID , 'PREV COMP');
        //I've also tried return echo anchor(...)
    }

}
```

further down on the page:

```
<div id="prevBtnContainer"><? hideButton($prevAvailCompID); ?></div>
```

Comment: would appreciate an upvote if my answer helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to return the `anchor()` function. You can just use as this

UPDATED CODE

```
public function test(){

    ?>
    <h1>test H1</h1>
    <div id="prevBtnContainer"><?php $this->hideButton(0); ?></div>
    <div id="1prevBtnContainer"><?php $this->hideButton(1); ?></div>
    <?php

}

private  function hideButton($prevCompID)
{
    if($prevCompID == 0)
    {
        echo anchor('/getcomps/getSpecificComp/'.$prevCompID , 'PREV COMP');
    }
}
```

I've tested this in my CodeIgniter and its working.

Comment: I've updated my code to give a clear idea how it worked.